# Why does this page shows only one post?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

so this is my code for the favorites page:

```
@app.route('/favorites')
@login_required
def favorites():
    cur=mysql.connection.cursor()
    r = cur.execute("SELECT post_id FROM favorites WHERE username = %s",[session['username']])
    if r==0:
        msg='No favorites Found'
        return render_template('favoritest.html',msg=msg)
    else:
        data=cur.fetchall()
        for row in data:
            pos_id = row["post_id"]
        cur.execute("SELECT* FROM posts WHERE id=%s ORDER BY created_at DESC",[pos_id])
        naa=cur.fetchall()
        cur.close()
        return render_template("favoritest.html",naa = naa)
```

and this is my template:

```
{% block body %}
        {% for itm in naa %} 
            <tr>
<td><a href="posts/{{itm['id']}}/{{itm['title']}}">{{itm['title']}}</a></td></tr>
        {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

it's only showing one post even if there was more than one, so what's the problem here and how to fix it?

*THANKS*

Comment: You only fetch the data for the last `pos_id`.

Comment: @Matthias so how to fetch for all `pos_id`s ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this snippet,

```
for row in data:
    pos_id = row["post_id"]
cur.execute("SELECT* FROM posts WHERE id=%s ORDER BY created_at DESC",[pos_id])
```

You are running the database query only once. So you should include it in the for loop like this:

```
for row in data:
    pos_id = row["post_id"]
    cur.execute("SELECT* FROM posts WHERE id=%s ORDER BY created_at DESC",[pos_id])
```

Realized this from @Matthias comment

**Update:**

```
naa = []
for row in data:
    pos_id = row["post_id"]
    cur.execute("SELECT* FROM posts WHERE id=%s ORDER BY created_at DESC",[pos_id])
    naa.append(cur.fetchall())
cur.close()
return render_template("favoritest.html",naa = naa)
```

Comment: @lawlawi, can you show the output of this query ```SELECT* FROM posts WHERE id=%s ORDER BY created_at DESC```, where you replace the ```%s``` by a sample post_id ?

Comment: I am suspecting that it returns only one row and you thus need to append the result to a list and return it

Comment: I didn't understand what do u mean, but the output of `pos_id` is just one result : `10` (the id of one post)

Comment: How to append the result and return it?

Comment: Now we have a solution.

Comment: yes we do have a solution @Matthias, Thank you a lot Saurabh P Bhandari for ur time and for everything :) I appreciate it